# How can I move (displace) TextBoxes created during runtime, referring to them by name? VBA

Tags: vba, textbox, runtime

So I have created a user form that will take input from the user to create a tool that will help in the evaluation of financial investments for my job. My user form takes into account any possible revenues and expenses generated by the investment, by any number of years that the investment will be useful. To do this I added 3 buttons, one that creates a new revenue row, another creates a new expenses row and the last a new years column, giving me two matrices of rev x years and expenses x years. If you need more details let me know!

The small "+" buttons seen add rows of revenues or expenses or columns of years. My problem is that when I add a row of revenues I have to displace the expenses down, even those created in run-time. My approach to this has been to use the controls collection and the name of the text box (which I have made into a matrix: e1y1, e2y2, e1y2, e2y2,... and so forth) using some for each statements and a couple of loops. The program runs and compiles properly, but the only things shifting down are the labels and frames, which are outside the for each and loops code. I'm attaching the relevant code but if there's anything else you need let me know, your help is suuuper appreciated!!

```
Private Sub moveControls()

    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim cell As TextBox
    Let y = 0
    Let e = 0

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
        cell = ctl
            Do While y < years
                Do While e < expenses
                    'Names of the small cells that are in a grid
                    ' which are the expense values
                    If cell.name = "e" & e & "y" & y Then
                        cell.top = cell.top + 19
                    End If
                    'Names of the larger cells on the left under
                    ' "Expenses" which are the expense names
                    If cell.Name = "expenses" & e Then
                        cell.top = cell.top + 19
                    End If
                    e = e + 1
                Loop
                y = y + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next ctl

    'This part of the code executes perfectly
    revenuesframe.top = revenuesframe.top + 19
    expenseslbl.top = expenseslbl.top + 19
    addxpsbutton.top = addxpsbutton.top + 19

End Sub
```

Comment: `If cell.name = "e" & g & "y" & a Then`  what is `a` ?

Comment: That should have been y, already changed it, thanks for the pointer, but it still doesn't work properly. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Don't you need to reset e and y for each control?  you might find it easier to loop though e any y and reference the controls directly (eg) `Me.Controls("e" & y & "y" & y)` rather than looping through all the controls and then through e and y...

Comment: In that case, how will I reference the control that meets the criteria of name "e" & e & "y" & y? And how can I access its .top property?

Comment: `Dim c: Set c=Me.Controls("e" & e & "y" & y): c.Top=cTop+19` ?